# Prometheus query does not return attribut when using regex with the absent method

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to create an alert that uses this query:

```
absent(namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr",instance=~"instance01|instance02|instance03"})
```

This query checks for the absence of the process 'tnssnr'. However, when this process is missing, I only receive {groupname="tnslsnr"} in the result of the query, Since i'm using a regex in the attribut 'instance', I cannot determine in which instance this process is missing.

Could you please help me understand how I can make the query return the 'instance' without creating multiple queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this query returns you result, that means, that process 'tnssnr' is not present on **all** of the instances matching your regex.

To check **each** instance and alert for them, you'll need to invoke `absent` for every instance separately. This can be done within a single query but with a bit of repetition:

```
absent(namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr",instance="instance01"})
 or absent(namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr",instance="instance02"})
 or absent(namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr",instance="instance03"})
```

Alternatively, you can employ some logic with `unless` operand to get full list of servers, and then exclude from them ones with process `tnssnr`. This might look something like

```
up{instance=~"instance01|instance02|instance03"} unless on(instance) namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr"}
```

Here, `up` returns all servers filtered out according to your regex (if you don't have `up`, use any other similar metric), and `unless on(instance)` excludes any servers that have results in query `namedprocess_namegroup_num_threads{groupname="tnslsnr"}`